# React Component running after I change page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I've got two react components, and for some reason one of them is running again (and causing a nasty bug) when I click another to go to another component.

My guess is that this is because I am running some asynchronous code for geolocation in my component constructor, but I don't know enough about React to be 100% certain of this.

The showPosition method makes an API call based on a user's location and other variables.

```
class Cards extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
        }
        this.showPosition = this.showPosition.bind(this);
      }
    ...

render() {
          if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <Loading />;
          }
    // The lines below this ALWAYS get run, even several seconds after I 
    // have been on my new component!
          console.log("state value new");
          console.log(this.state.data);
            return (
    <Page className="main-page">
    <div className="cards">
    {this.state.data.merchants.map( (merchant, index) =>
     <CardRow
     merchant={{merchant}}
     count={index}
     className={'card-color-' + index}
      />
  )}
    </div>
    </Page>
);
        }
    }
```

This cards component creates a child component called CardRow, and then that component creates several Card and PromoCard component children.

I won't link the full card, but the way I am accessing the component that breaks is this way - a user clicks the link, and is directed to the chat component:

```
      <Link to={{
              pathname: "/chat/" + this.state.merchant.id,
              state: {merchant: this.state.merchant}
      }}>
```

I made a toy component for chat, and everything loads fine, but then the render function in `<Cards />` runs **again**, which messes up my entire chat interface.

Why is this happening? Is it related to my geolocation code in my constructor? Something else potentially?

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory leak, it is not a good practice to set listeners in your constructor.
You must use lifecycle methods (componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount, etc...)

the componentDidMount lifecycle method is the right place to set a listener

```
constructor() {
 this.showPosition = this.showPosition.bind(this);
 this.unmounted = false;
}

componentDidMount() {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
 }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // indicate that the component has been unmounted
  this.unmounted = true;
}

showPosition() {
  // exiting early if the component was unmounted
  // prevent any update using setState
  if (this.unmounted) { return; }

  // more code...
}
```

Comment: Even with these changes, I am still getting the render() method from <Cards /> being called on my <Chat /> component.

Comment: Maybe something to do with CSSTransition?

Comment: you have the stack trace, that will be helpful